# BalloonTipClicked (Closed/Shown) Sender/EventArgs

Tags: c#, balloon-tip

I am trying to identify which BalloonTip (NotifyIcon) sent the BalloonTipClicked (and Closed, and Shown) events as I have a few different scenarios where balloons may be shown and they aren't all the same nor will have the same expected actions.

Does anyone know if you can identify *anything* about the BalloonTip that send the Clicked/Closed/Shown events?

Comment: Tags in titles are redundant, please don't add them.

Comment: Wasn't aware that I added a tag to the title ... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does seem like this is a tough cookie to crack. Thanks to @keyboardP for his suggestion as it is a viable alternative, but I ended up creating a special method and enum (as SO didn't email me when I got answers or comments ... I need to check my prefs ...):

```
internal static void ShowTip(Int32 timeout, String tipTitle, String tipText, ToolTipIcon tipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None, ShowTipAction tipAction = ShowTipAction.STA_Shown_WriteReg, String linkToOpen = "")
{
    if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Nothing) == 0) // if STA_Nothing has not been passed
    {
        if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Clicked_Nothing) == 0 && ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Clicked_OpenLink) > 0 || (tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Clicked_WriteReg) > 0))
            trayIcon.BalloonTipClicked += (s, e) => // if STA_Clicked_Nothing has not been passed and either STA_Clicked_OpenLink or STA_Clicked_WriteReg has been passed
            { // when this balloon tip is clicked
                if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Clicked_OpenLink) > 0) // open passed link
                    MethodorProcessToLaunchSite(linktoOpen);
                if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Clicked_WriteReg) > 0) // write notification indicator to registry
                    RegWriteMethod;
            };
        if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Closed_Nothing) == 0 && (tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Closed_WriteReg) > 0) // if STA_Closed_Nothing has not been passed and STA_Closed_WriteReg has been passed
            trayIcon.BalloonTipClosed += (s, e) => { RegWriteMethod; }; // when this balloon tip is closed, write notification indicator to registry
        if ((tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Shown_Nothing) == 0 && (tipAction & ShowTipAction.STA_Shown_WriteReg) > 0) // if STA_Shown_Nothing has not been passed and STA_Shown_WriteReg has been passed
            trayIcon.BalloonTipShown += (s, e) => { RegWriteMethod; }; // when this balloon tip is shown, write notification indicator to registry
    }

    // Show the balloon tip
    trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, tipTitle, tipText, tipIcon);
}
```

... and the enum:

```
[Flags]
internal enum ShowTipAction
{
    STA_Nothing = 1,
    STA_Clicked_Nothing = 2,
    STA_Clicked_OpenLink = 4,
    STA_Clicked_WriteReg = 8,
    STA_Closed_Nothing = 16,
    STA_Closed_WriteReg = 32,
    STA_Shown_Nothing = 64,
    STA_Shown_WriteReg = 128
}
```

Between the lambdas and the enum, I can make this as extensible as I like. 
I know it's not really the prettiest solution, but it works; surprisingly well!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a workaround but you could create a method (or an extension method)

```
public static void ShowBalloonAndUpdate(this NotifyIcon ni, int timeout, string title, string text, ToolTipIcon icon )
{
    ni.BalloonTipTitle = title;
    ni.BalloonTipText = text;
    ni.BalloonTipIcon = icon;
    ni.ShowBalloonTip(timeout);
}
```

When you call the BalloonTip with that method, it will update the properties of the NotifyIcon.

```
myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonAndUpdate(1000, "Hello" "My Message", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

These properties can then be read in any  of the BalloonTip events. You can decide what to do based on one of the properties (e.g. `BalloonTitle`)

```
private void myNotifyIcon_BalloonTipShown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    NotifyIcon ni = sender as NotifyIcon;
    if(ni != null)   
    {
        switch(ni.BalloonTitle)
        {
            case "Hello":
                  //Hello tooltip was shown
                  break;
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the code! It's a bit different to what I have used (I'll be posting it as an answer after this comment)